# Ask awk to print the specific word which contains a few words

Tags: string, awk

for example I have a sentence with words which starts with ! in a log file

```
0 1 ! abs tHfih(t) qcds bbc(u)
```

so with a code as below I can find that line

```
  awk '
  /[Tt][Hh][Ff]/ { if ($3 ~ /!/) {print "a"; exit 0}}
```

how can I tell the awk to print the whole line and the complete word which contains thf "tHfih(t)"?

print the line

```
awk '
/[Tt][Hh][Ff]/ { if ($3 ~ /!/) {print "the line containing the match"; exit 0}}
```

print the word

```
awk '
    /[Tt][Hh][Ff]/ { if ($3 ~ /!/) {print "the word containing the match"; exit 0}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this might be simpler

```
awk 'tolower($0) ~ /thf/ && $3=="!"'
```

UPDATE

if you don't know the position of the searched field.  You can scan all fields for a match.  For example, for the lines that has `!` on third position print the line number and word that contains `thf` case insensitive

```
awk '$3=="!"{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(tolower($i)~/thf/) print NR, $i}'
```

UPDATE 2

if you want to switch matching words vs line

```
awk -vw=1 '$3=="!"{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(tolower($i)~/thf/) print w?$i:$0}' file
```

set w=0 for full line printing and to 1 for word printing.  Note that this assumes a single match in the line, otherwise it will print all matches (and that many lines in line mode).

Comment: First, how to print the single word or the whole sentence that was my question! 
Second, My input is a large file about 1-2 maybe even 5mb doesn't toolbar make my code slow?

Comment: by default it print the line which has all the words in it.  The file size doesn't matter.  If you want to print only fourth field `awk .. {print $4}` will do.

Comment: so please clarify how to tell to print all the line or just that single word which it has found.
cause in my case I dunno where that word is!
it can be $4 it can be $5

Comment: it's a good trick but I was hoping awk could just print the matching word, or the whole line with adding another loop